# Substring, As, Count issue

Tags: sql

I need to extract part of an ID Field (ParcelID) and then use the count field to count the number of times it is in the database.  This is what I did: I created a view with the following:

```
SELECT  ParcelID, SUBSTRING(ParcelID, 1, 12) AS PID, COUNT(PID) AS PIDCount
FROM    dbo.RptCDMGISExtract
```

It says that Invalid Column Name.  I guess I understand (PID) does not exist.  How can I complete this?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you seem to want:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ParcelID, 1, 12) AS PID, COUNT(*) AS PIDCount
FROM dbo.RptCDMGISExtract
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ParcelID, 1, 12);
```

Note that many databases would use `LEFT(ParcelID, 12)` instead of the `SUBSTRING()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(id, 1, 12) AS PID,
       COUNT(*) AS PIDCount
FROM new_schema.new_table
GROUP BY PID;
```